# iPhone 5s fingerprint sensor

Tags: iphone, hardware

My fingerprint sensor on my iPhone 5s is not working, but the home button is working. I want to replace the fingerprint sensor. Is it possible to just buy a new fingerprint sensor - home button assembly and replace it, and will it just work? I heard stories that fingerprint sensor is somehow hard wired with the motherboard and no other fingerprint sensor can replace the original one. Is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to replace or repair the fingerprint sensor is for Apple to do it for you.

It is tied to the secure enclave in the CPU & any unauthorised tampering will disable it.